# How can I add a reply option to a comment form?

Tags: php, forms, comments

I made a comment form but I want to add a simple "reply" option. I spent hours trying to do that but I didn't have any luck. I don't need a login page, just a reply option. Please help!

This is the form code on the php document:

```
<html>

<form action="" method="post">

<label>Name: <br><input type="text" name="name"><br></label>

<label>Message: <br><textarea cols="35" rows="5" name="mes">
</textarea></label><br>

<input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">

</form>
</html>

<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$text = $_POST["mes"];
$post = $_POST["post"];

if($post){
#WRITE DOWN COMMENTS#

$write = fopen("com.txt", "a+");
fwrite($write, "<u><b> $name</b></u><br>$text<br>");
fclose($write);

#DISPLAY COMMENTS#

$read = fopen("com.txt", "r+t");
echo "All comments:<br>";

while(!feof($read)){
echo fread ($read, 1024);
}

fclose($read);

}

else{
#DISPLAY COMMENTS#

$read=fopen("com.txt", "r+t");
echo "All comments:<br>";

while(!feof($read)){
echo fread ($read, 1024);
}

fclose($read);

}
?>
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: That's very weird. You want to save replies in TXT file ? Why don't you use database?

Comment: I am requested not to use database. Its not really my choice. Can you help with adding a reply option? I have been trying this for 3 days..

Comment: By "reply", did you mean replying to a specific comment?

Comment: Yes, so the user may reply to a comment... kind of like how I am replying to you right now..